# getting an object using its tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, tags

I am making a program and I need to get the name of the UIImageView from its tag. How would I do this? I saw something called viewWithTag but I think that is just for buttons. I am using Xcode with objective c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewWithTag:` is for any `UIView` (or subclass thereof). This does work for buttons since they are a subclass of `UIView`. You can set the tags programmatically or in XCode and can use `viewWithTag:` to get the view. Just make sure that each view has a unique tag, otherwise you might end up grabbing the wrong one.

As far as the name part, I am not sure exactly what you are after so if you need further direction please clarify your point.

Answer (score 0):

Before you wanna use the tag property of the imageView you need to set the objects tag with this 
[UIImageView setTag:123].

After setting it's tag you can reach the object with 
(UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:123]

Answer (score -1):

As UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, which has the tag attribute use this viewWithTag and try below:-

```
  UIImageView *myImageView = (UIImageView *)    
     [yoursuperView viewWithTag:15];
```

call this method on your superview where all the UIImageViews reside in.

Comment: Thanks! I was really confused on this. It makes sense now.